# Unable to log in into Ubuntu 17.10 after Nvidia driver rollback

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Lenovo legion notebook with Nvidia 1050Ti GPU along with Intel graphics. I installed Ubuntu 17.0 in june and painstakingly installed Nvidia drivers 375.22 and Cuda etc. This morning after an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10, nvidia commands like `nvidia-smi` and `nvidia-settings` stopped working. I was getting errors that libnvidia.so was missing. I checked the Nvidia driver version with `lspci -k` and found it to be 384.xx. In order to fix this issue, I made the mistake of running the old driver installer (ver 375.22) and rebooting.

Now I am not even able to reach the login screen. I tried to restore `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`from an older version by booting into recovery, with no luck. Is there a way to fix this (atleast be able to run the system using Intel graphics) without doing a fresh install?

Comment: You should be able to select your older kernel (with driver) at the Grub prompt early during boot. DON'T try to mix different drivers with different kernels - it won't work, as you discovered. 'Drivers' are really just another name for kernel modules, must be compiled for their kernel, and won't work with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with you.
And I solved it by

**sudo apt-get purge nvidia***

in the recovery mode.

Honestly, it is not the best way to solve the issue, but it seems to be the only way.